# Ubuntu Server is not accessible from the Internet

Tags: 14.04, internet, webserver, router, port-forwarding

My linaro ubuntu server is not accessible from the Internet
I have a static IP from my ISP.

I would like to diagnose what exactly goes wrong.

Ubuntu server is connected to my router (Asus RT-N12D1) as well as other windows 10 pro machine (it is my PC)

On router I did regular ISP setting + Port Forwarding for HTTP protocol as you can seen on following screenshot. Please bare in mind that source target IP (my external static IP) is hidden with ***-signs for security purposes. There are actually regular static IP that I can see on various "what is my ip"-services.
[image]

For now I would like to install and adjust LAMP-server and make it accessible via internet. But unfortunately  I installed apache2, php, mysql and as far as I understood works only apache2 and only if I call server using local home network by local ip 192.168.1.55
SSH connection also via local IP works fine.

## So, in my situation, what should I do to recognize the problem?

Comment: You have tagged Ubuntu 14.04 which is EOL (14.04 LTS) and thus off-topic, or just off-topic (14.04 ESM supported by Canonical).  Please clarify your Ubuntu, as if it's Ubuntu 14.04 it's off-topic and you should upgrade to a supported release of Ubuntu, or use your Ubuntu Advantage support options.

Comment: The last sentence seems to contain a lot of key information...but written unclearly. Please edit your question to clearly state: 1) If you can successfully ping your machine from another on the same local network, 2) If you can successfully ssh into your machine on the same local network. 3) if you can successfully access webpages from your machine on the same local network. 4) The complete list of firewall rules (if any) on your Ubuntu machine.